# Set titles on plotly pie charts subplots

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Hi guys I need some advise on setting up titles for subplot pie charts. For a project that I'm doing I need to show the crime distribution(violent/non-violent) for a given Police District. End end goal should be a plot comprised of multiple subplots where each Subplot should have a title. Currently I don't know how to set the subtitles.Ex of a title would be 'Violent Crime Distribution Police District1'

Example of dataframes showing violent/-non violent crime distribution for Police District 1
    pd_1D
            labels  values
    0  Non-Violent    2097
    1      Violent    1362

```
pd_2D
        labels  values
0      Violent    1710
1  Non-Violent    1660
```

plotly syntax i'm using:

```
fig= {
    'data':[{
        'labels':pd_1D['labels'],
        'values':pd_1D['values'],
        'type':'pie',
        'name':'PD 1D',
        'domain': {'x': [0, .20],
                       'y': [0, .49]},
        'textinfo':'blahcjakjsa'
    },
        {
        'labels':pd_2D['labels'],
        'values':pd_2D['values'],
        'type':'pie',
        'name':'PD 2',
        'domain': {'x': [.35, .55],
                       'y': [0, .49]},
        'textinfo':'PD 2D'    
        }
    ],      
 'layout': {'title': 'Violent/Non-Violent crime distribution/Police District Number'}
}
iplot(fig, filename='pie_chart_subplots'))
```

Polty documentation:
https://plot.ly/python/pie-charts/

I'm able to achieve this using matplotlib library but not in plotly. See below print screen when using matplotlib:
[Setting up subtitles using matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAAGS.png)

Comment: What is `iplot`?

Comment: Hi I imported  some plotly modules as iplot: "from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot". So once again what I want to achive is to set for each subplot a title. I'm comparing violent/non-violent crime distribution for a county in US. So I would like that each individual subplot to have a title....i.e district 1, district 2 so on and so fort

Comment: Hi guys. I have re-edited my question. Could you please check it out and tell me if it's clear what I want to achieve? Thanks

Comment: I have voted to reopen. However, you might be better off just asking a new question. And if I were you I'd show the matplotlib code that does what you want. Unfortunately I don't know plotly so I can't help here.

Comment: Can close this one. This can be achieved using text annotations. Official ref: https://plot.ly/javascript/text-and-annotations/ .